# Automatically detect adb lost connection to android sdk device

Tags: selenium, connection, timeout, webdriver, adb

I want to execute my C# tests on an android emulator but every time adb loses connection to the android device the execution fails cause adb can't forward the port anymore. I use the android-server.apk for my tests (selenium).
(my port forwarding: adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080)

Is there a way to prevent adb from losing connection to the android devices or can I check automatically if the connection is lost to run a batch file for reconnecting?

Greetings
Cava

Comment: Which version of apk do you use? If you use 2.32.0 try to use 2.21.0. This may solve the problem.

Comment: I use 2.21
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=android-server.apk&can=1&q=android

I couldn't register my Android node to my Selenium Hub with v.2.32 (using flynnid's python script)